# How to check if toplevel exists after destroying it in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to check if a particular Toplevel has been destroyed, which happens after a certain button is pressed, so that I can then do something else in the program (i.e. create a NEW Toplevel).

Supposedly, after the initial toplevel is closed by the user, the output on the shell should be "N". This would indicate that the program understood that the initial toplevel no longer existed, allowing me to carry onto the next stage in that particular `if not t1.winfo_exists():` clause (see below).

This output does not happen. Nothing happens on the output. I used 'winfo_exists()' and I cannot find what I have done incorrectly.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

t1 = Toplevel(root)
t1.title('REG') 

def GetREG():
    global e, reg
    reg = e.get() # find out the user input
    # Destroy the toplevel:
    t1.destroy() # after the user presses the SubmitButton

label = Label(t1, text="Enter your REG:")
label.pack()

e = Entry(t1) # for the user to input their REG
e.pack()

SubmitButton = Button(t1,text='Submit',command=GetREG) # button to submit entry
SubmitButton.pack(side='bottom')

if not t1.winfo_exists(): # TRYING TO CHECK when the does not exist
    # supposedly, this should occur after the SubmitButton is pressed
    # which shold allow me to then carry out the next step in the program
    print("No")

root.mainloop()
```

Could it be that when the user destroys a window, this is not recognized as a non-existent state? It doesn't work either when I 'delete' the t1 toplevel with the cross, or when it gets deleted via the SubmitButton (with `t1.destroy()` in `GetREG()`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time you check for `t1.winfo_exists()`, the window still exists because you're calling that function about a millisecond after it has been created. How is tkinter supposed to know that you want that `if` statement to wait for the window to be destroyed?

If you want to wait for it to be destroyed before executing more code you can use the method `wait_window`, which is like `mainloop` in that it processes events until the window is destroyed.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
t1 = Toplevel(root)    
...
root.wait_window(t1)

# there is now no need to check, since it's not possible to get
# here until the window has been destroyed.

root.mainloop()
```